# Simple Lightweight C# IDE to ship with my product

Tags: c#, ide

I've developed a Product which has scripting functionality. I've used the CS Script(C# script) engine to provide this.

I am now looking for a simple and lightweight IDE to ship together with my product. The IDE needs to be very simple and plain for my customers. Ideally it should look something like Notepad++ but has auto-completion feature.

**NOTEPAD++**
I know some people may suggest Notepad++ with which has an auto-completion plugin. However,the problem with Notepad++ is that it is VERY COMMON in most of my customers machine, therefore I may not be able to override the installation with my Customized Notepad++ files.

**VISUAL STUDIO EXPRESS**
Visual Studio Express has been suggested in another topic, however, Visual Studio Express is NOT light weight. I want something easy and portable.

Comment: Did you check out VSCode? http://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: Look at FastColoredTextBox on CodeProject

Comment: If you can spend the money look at SyntaxEditor - ActiPro: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/windowsforms/syntaxeditor

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! VSCode seems awesome